# При попытке установить оплату криптовалютой в телеграм бота ошибка: pip error: python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pip, bitcoin

пытаюсь подключить оплату криптовалютой к телеграм боту, пробовал bitcoinlib  - вроде работает, но ходят слухи что при 100+ юзерах она ломается, ещё там криво работают ltc кошельки. Пробовал устанавливать **"pip install pywallet"** и **"pip install bipwallet"**. Но выдаёт ошибку, решения нигде не нашел, буду признателен любой помощи.

**Ошибка:**

```
 Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r8zrjs_h\protobuf_e042f315c2434acb80a3cf3dac93bcbd\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
          from distutils.command.build_py import build_py_2to3 as _build_py
      ImportError: cannot import name 'build_py_2to3' from 'distutils.command.build_py' (C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_py.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

вроде есть решение, устанавливай protobuf с гитхаба и добавляй в path

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install "setuptools<58.0.0"
```

С помощью этой команды я смог избавиться от этой проблемы, но далее, появляется другая ошибка:

> "note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: legacy-install-failure"

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.